# Как передать переменные в view blade

Tags: laravel

Есть метод контроллера упрощённый:

```
public function toBlade()
{
     $tir = 4;
     return view(app.blade.php); // как передать переменную в view
}
```

Как передать сразу много переменных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам 2 варианта.

```
1. return view('app.blade.php', ['tir' => $tir]);
2. return view('app.blade.php', compact('tir'));
```

Читайте [документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#passing-data-to-views) там всё есть.

Comment: есть еще и 3 вариант return view('app')->with('tir',$tir);